# Cannot get rid of Arg with FullSimplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, complex

This expression keeps showing up in a much larger expression, making it seem more complicated than it is, because this expression is necessarily just 0:

```
$Assumptions = a ∈ Reals;
ComplexExpand[Arg[a + I a] + Arg[a - I a]] // FullSimplify
```

> `Arg[(1 - I)a] + Arg[(1 + I)a]`

I know it won't compute `Arg` when its argument is not numeric, but shouldn't there be a way to recognize when two `Arg` expressions are equal and opposite??

--Edit--

As BlacKow pointed out, Arg works with the a > 0 assumption for the expression above. However, I run into a problem as soon as the expression gets more complicated, i.e.:

```
$Assumptions = {a \[Element] Reals,a>0};
ComplexExpand[ Arg[a + I a^2] + Arg[a - I a^2]]//FullSimplify
```

> `Arg[1-Ia]+Arg[1+Ia]`

Comment: `$Assumptions = {a > 0}` fixes it

Comment: Thank you, that does work for the expression in my question. However, it weirdly does not work when I try it on an even slightly more complicated one:
$Assumptions = {a \[Element] Reals,a>0};
ComplexExpand[ Arg[a + I a^2] + Arg[a - I a^2]]//FullSimplify


Arg[1-\[ImaginaryI] a]+Arg[1+\[ImaginaryI] a]
sorry, I don't know how to format the comments

Answer (score 1):

You could define a transformation function for `Simplify` to use.

```
xform[Arg[(1 + I) a_]] := a π/4
xform[Arg[(1 - I) a_]] := -a π/4
```

then

```
Simplify[Arg[a + I a] + Arg[a - I a], TransformationFunctions -> {xform}]
```

> `0`

Comment: Thanks, I might be able to do something with TransformationFunctions.
The full expression in all its ugliness is "Arg[2 -a^2 + I a Sqrt[4 - a^2]] + Arg[2 - a (a + I Sqrt[4 - a^2])]" so I would have to adapt it a little, but it could work

Comment: @partyphysics. I can only work with the information that you give in your question.

Comment: I know, I was just hoping there was a general solution. I may encounter the same problem with a different expression soon

Answer (score 1):

ReplaceRepeated seems to solve it. I couldn't get Replace or Simplify with Transformation Functions to work, because sometimes the Arg terms would have additional Arg terms within them after operating on them with ComplexExpand. This is the code that works with a sample expression (the one that was bugging me):

```
someuglyexpression =E^(I*(Arg[2 + h (-h + Sqrt[-4 + h^2])] +Arg[2 - h (h + Sqrt[-4 + h^2])]))
ReplaceArgWithArcTan={Arg[z_]->ArcTan[Im[ComplexExpand[z]]/Re[ComplexExpand[z]]]} ;
lessuglyexpression = someuglyexpression //.ReplaceArgWithArcTan //FullSimplify
```

before:
[image: ugly expression]

after:
1

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the case $a=0$ is part of the issue, even though `Arg[0]`is defined to be 0. For some reason all of these work:

```
Assuming[a > 0, Arg[a + I a] + Arg[a - I a] // Simplify]
Assuming[a > 0, ComplexExpand[Arg[a + I a] + Arg[a - I a]] // Simplify]
Assuming[a < 0, ComplexExpand[Arg[a + I a] + Arg[a - I a]] // Simplify]
(*
0
0
*)
```

However this does not:

```
Assuming[a \[Element] Reals && a != 0, 
         ComplexExpand[Arg[a + I a] + Arg[a - I a]] // Simplify]
(*
Arg[(1 - I) a] + Arg[(1 + I) a]
*)
```

Comment: Very strange, I do not understand this